# Can you change the date format of the recieved field?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Right now, the received field takes up a lot of real estate on my screen in its current date format:

> Thurs 9/10/2009 7:02 AM (as an example)

Is there any way I can change the format on this field to another format, for example?

> 9/10/09 7:02

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Outlook 2007**

Right click the field> Format Columns...

Select an appropriate format from the format dropdown.

[image]

Comment: can you put in a custom format ?

Comment: Outlook 2007 uses system-wide format; it can be specified in Control Panel / Region / Formats / Additional Settings / Date.

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook 2003,

View > Arrange > Current > Format > Received > and choose required Format from drop down.

Comment: That's potentially better than changing system date settings :)

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2k3, my date field shows as 'Thu 10/09/2009 18:21'

I'm pretty sure this is tied to the "Regional and Language Options" Control Panel (under XP), where I've customized my date format.